# API for registering your app to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sdk, azure-billing-api

I am trying to write an app that, upon receiving the credentials of an Azure user, will be able to show him various pieces of information using the Azure billing apis. 
However, the following git sample that shows how to use one of those apis, lists a series of steps that should be done in the Azure cloud platform in order for things to work, and these steps need to be done by the user himself. Specifically, step 1 talks about registering an app and configuring it so that it has access and permissions to use the apis. 
Only after those steps, will I be able to access the billing apis and retrieve his information.

Seeing as how I don't want the user to have to do anything after he gives me his username and password, is there an API or some other automated way with which I can register my app to view his account?

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/billing-dotnet-usage-api

Ideally, I would want some sort of imaginary code that maybe looks like:

```
someObj obj = someAPI.loginToAzureWithCredentials("123456", "someUserName")
obj.registerApplication();
```

Obviously the "code" is very lacking in details, but it's just for emphasizing what I'm searching for.

Comment: Well, you could use a multi-tenant app I guess? Though of course the user still needs to do an interactive login to consent to the permissions you require.

Comment: Hey can you please elaborate what's a multi-tenant app is, or, more importantly, why will it fit my scenario?

Comment: This one explains it fairly well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview :)

Comment: Basically, you register the app in your AAD tenant, and define what permissions it requires on other APIs. Then someone from another AAD tenant can go through sign up, and use it with their account. They will have to accept the permissions you require first of course.

Comment: I'm sorry I read it but still don't fully understand.

Comment: @juunas I'm sorry I read it but still don't fully understand. Let's say I write an app that's gonna be a simple website with the sole purpose of showing an Azure user his total bill, and this goal is achieved with the billing apis. I want the sign up to this website to be a one-time procedure that includes giving me credentials to his azure account. Is that the scenario you refer to?

Comment: Yeah, you can register a multi-tenant app in your tenant and require access to the billing API on it. Then when a user signs in from another tenant, they'll be asked to give your app permission to access the billing API. Once the user gives that access, your app can then acquire access tokens and call the API in their tenant. Your app should never take the user's credentials, it should delegate authentication to Azure AD, and go through one of the standard authentication flows to get access tokens.

Comment: The authentication flows are a slightly broad topic, but the documentation is relatively good for those too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios